# The increment counter in method not working for java

Tags: java

I am developing two separate program which involve method call from each side.Program A is MyNoteCenter.java and program B is SocketServer.java. There consist of a method call in MyNoteCenter to trigger the method in the SocketServer for download the resource, so the counter in SocketServer will increment by 1. when I click the button download inside the MyNoteCenter, it will contact the SocketServer for download request and increment the counter by one if SocketServer receive valid argument but why my counter only rise one time? it will only function well for the first time I click the download button but when I click the second time, the counter still showing 1

This is some portion of my SocketServer program

```
 public String getDownload()
{
    int c = 0;
    c = c + 1;
    switch(software)
    {

        case "1" :
            message = "ITune";
        //    counter++;
            break;

        case "2" :
            message = "ZoneAlarm";
        //  counter++;
            break;

        case "3" :
            message = "Winrar";
        //  counter++;
            break;

        case "4" :
            message = "Audacity";
        //  counter++;
            break;

    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your download is\n" +message+ "\n the number of download is\n"+c);
    return message;

}
```

This is the method in MyNoteCenter, the method will be trigger after the btn2 is click which is download button, the runCC method will contact the SocketServer method for download

```
 public static void runCC(String software,String id,String name,String job,String country)
       {
         SocketServer dc = new SocketServer(software,id,name,job,country);
         String ServerReplyMessage = dc.getDownload();
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Downloading :\n" +ServerReplyMessage);
         int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to continue?", "Confirm",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if (answer == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please click close button");
        }
       else
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please proceed");
       }
```

http://codepad.org/ >>my full SocketServer program

Answer (score 0):

You are re initializing `c` every time you run the method.

`c` should be a field defined within the class that will maintain value every time you need to increment it OR evaluate it's current value.

```
 public class MyClass {

    private int c = 0;


    public String getDownload() {
       c++;

       switch case...
    }

 }
```

Comment: declare my c variable as global variable ?

Comment: @doe global to the class yes, but private within the scope of the class

Comment: but the counter remain the same, here is my new modify program http://codepad.org/W5TkxIpq. I don know whether I follow the right instruction or not, I had make a change to c variable which is global instead of local variable

Comment: I compile it ady using cmd in my laptop, codepad is for me to share my code, the code inside the codepad is one part of my sample program only,there have other client program to make the program execute